# How to create Threads in main()

Tags: java, static

I have a very simple program with a Threads. Suppose I want that the thread starts after some code (i.e. in the middle of program). How do I achieve this?

When I try to start the thread in main() after the code(code given below), it shows the error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context.

```
public class Main {

    public class MyThread implements Runnable {

       public void run() {
        //do something
       }
    }

    Thread t1 = new Thread (new MyThread());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // some code
        t1.start();
        //some code
    }
}
```

**Can anybody plese tell me how to correct the error.**

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need access to the `Thread` variable outside of your `main`, then the correct solution would be to simply use a local variable:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     // some code
     Thread t1 = new Thread (new MyThread());
     t1.start();
     //some code
}
```

Otherwise, you'd *either* need to make `t1` `static` *or* let your code run inside a non-static method (i.e. create an instance of your `main` class and do your actual work in a method that you *call* from `main`).

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to instantiate your thread from within the main function, as it is a static function.

```
 public class Main {

 public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
     //do something
    }
 }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Thread t1 = new Thread (new MyThread());

         // some code
         t1.start();
         //some code

     }
 }
```